# Can't browse Photos library in Final Cut Pro X

Tags: final-cut-pro, final-cut-pro-x, photos

I can't browse the Photos library from within FCPX. It just says "Open Photos to see your photos in this list". Yes, I've closed and reopened both Photos and FCPX.

I had everything working, but now I'm using a different Photos library on a different harddrive, and it has stopped working as before.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Photos app (not FCPX), go to Preferences, then click "Use as System Photo Library". Then FCPX will be able to find the library file.

Comment: I did as you said. Even created two photos libraries, since my (the only one) was of course grayed out. Did not helped. FCX still see photos as empty junk